# Node JS Calculate Sum From JSON Array By Reduce Getting Nan

Tags: javascript, node.js, reduce

I am trying to use reduce to do the sum in the JSON Array . and the return value I am getting `NAN`

Anyone please help me to check my code is correct or not.

Her is my code

```js
const reduceBids = [ { id: 'd4f82532-d38a-421f-81d5-795dcfc7cd70',
    vehicleId: '20f3f453-774c-4e4e-9dd6-a3b3468e42f4',
    userId: '0d7a45e7-3483-4cc6-95b0-12e551002a7a',
    bidAmount: 300,
    fullName: 'Hanuman' },
  { id: 'f4631745-7181-4d9c-92ce-948751fa7e14',
    vehicleId: '20f3f453-774c-4e4e-9dd6-a3b3468e42f4',
    userId: 'bc9b172d-b8a2-48bd-8605-a13e9536dc00',
    bidAmount: 300,
    fullName: 'Venkatesh' },
  { id: '44422594-e69d-48cb-b8d1-7493b5275e26',
    vehicleId: '20f3f453-774c-4e4e-9dd6-a3b3468e42f4',
    userId: '0d7a45e7-3483-4cc6-95b0-12e551002a7a',
    bidAmount: 300,
    fullName: 'Hanuman' },
  { id: '747cb11d-1306-4638-b90e-cc197c3648e7',
    vehicleId: '20f3f453-774c-4e4e-9dd6-a3b3468e42f4',
    userId: '0d7a45e7-3483-4cc6-95b0-12e551002a7a',
    bidAmount: 300,
    fullName: 'Hanuman' },
  { id: '879364ba-d672-4ad9-a4b8-2cc29c3c912a',
    vehicleId: '20f3f453-774c-4e4e-9dd6-a3b3468e42f4',
    userId: '0d7a45e7-3483-4cc6-95b0-12e551002a7a',
    bidAmount: 300,
    fullName: 'Hanuman' },
  { id: '9bbb3ee3-7f27-4743-aa3e-553e399dce9a',
    vehicleId: '20f3f453-774c-4e4e-9dd6-a3b3468e42f4',
    userId: '0d7a45e7-3483-4cc6-95b0-12e551002a7a',
    bidAmount: 300,
    fullName: 'Hanuman' },
  { id: '4a7026c3-0688-42a7-bfe7-cbb733dcb656',
    vehicleId: '20f3f453-774c-4e4e-9dd6-a3b3468e42f4',
    userId: '0d7a45e7-3483-4cc6-95b0-12e551002a7a',
    bidAmount: 300,
    fullName: 'Hanuman' },
  { id: '7918cb18-0951-40b9-a687-7bb4a03d5bec',
    vehicleId: '20f3f453-774c-4e4e-9dd6-a3b3468e42f4',
    userId: '0d7a45e7-3483-4cc6-95b0-12e551002a7a',
    bidAmount: 300,
    fullName: 'Hanuman' },
  { id: 'b94b4f57-41c2-442e-85ae-d3ddceaaa985',
    vehicleId: '20f3f453-774c-4e4e-9dd6-a3b3468e42f4',
    userId: '0d7a45e7-3483-4cc6-95b0-12e551002a7a',
    bidAmount: 300,
    fullName: 'Hanuman' },
  { id: 'acfff167-3b71-4f60-a229-95b5444e25e9',
    vehicleId: '20f3f453-774c-4e4e-9dd6-a3b3468e42f4',
    userId: '0d7a45e7-3483-4cc6-95b0-12e551002a7a',
    bidAmount: 200,
    fullName: 'Hanuman' } ];

 const total = reduceBids.reduce((bid, currentBid) => {  
        return bid.bidAmount + currentBid.bidAmount;
});   

console.log(total);
```

I need to calculate the total amount of the `bidAmount` but instead of total.

I am getting `NAN` Please to run the code and check the output

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function's first argument represents the value evaluated in a previous step (accumulator) so your code should look like below:

```js
const reduceBids = [ { id: 'd4f82532-d38a-421f-81d5-795dcfc7cd70',
    vehicleId: '20f3f453-774c-4e4e-9dd6-a3b3468e42f4',
    userId: '0d7a45e7-3483-4cc6-95b0-12e551002a7a',
    bidAmount: 300,
    fullName: 'Hanuman' },
  { id: 'f4631745-7181-4d9c-92ce-948751fa7e14',
    vehicleId: '20f3f453-774c-4e4e-9dd6-a3b3468e42f4',
    userId: 'bc9b172d-b8a2-48bd-8605-a13e9536dc00',
    bidAmount: 300,
    fullName: 'Venkatesh' },
  { id: '44422594-e69d-48cb-b8d1-7493b5275e26',
    vehicleId: '20f3f453-774c-4e4e-9dd6-a3b3468e42f4',
    userId: '0d7a45e7-3483-4cc6-95b0-12e551002a7a',
    bidAmount: 300,
    fullName: 'Hanuman' },
  { id: '747cb11d-1306-4638-b90e-cc197c3648e7',
    vehicleId: '20f3f453-774c-4e4e-9dd6-a3b3468e42f4',
    userId: '0d7a45e7-3483-4cc6-95b0-12e551002a7a',
    bidAmount: 300,
    fullName: 'Hanuman' },
  { id: '879364ba-d672-4ad9-a4b8-2cc29c3c912a',
    vehicleId: '20f3f453-774c-4e4e-9dd6-a3b3468e42f4',
    userId: '0d7a45e7-3483-4cc6-95b0-12e551002a7a',
    bidAmount: 300,
    fullName: 'Hanuman' },
  { id: '9bbb3ee3-7f27-4743-aa3e-553e399dce9a',
    vehicleId: '20f3f453-774c-4e4e-9dd6-a3b3468e42f4',
    userId: '0d7a45e7-3483-4cc6-95b0-12e551002a7a',
    bidAmount: 300,
    fullName: 'Hanuman' },
  { id: '4a7026c3-0688-42a7-bfe7-cbb733dcb656',
    vehicleId: '20f3f453-774c-4e4e-9dd6-a3b3468e42f4',
    userId: '0d7a45e7-3483-4cc6-95b0-12e551002a7a',
    bidAmount: 300,
    fullName: 'Hanuman' },
  { id: '7918cb18-0951-40b9-a687-7bb4a03d5bec',
    vehicleId: '20f3f453-774c-4e4e-9dd6-a3b3468e42f4',
    userId: '0d7a45e7-3483-4cc6-95b0-12e551002a7a',
    bidAmount: 300,
    fullName: 'Hanuman' },
  { id: 'b94b4f57-41c2-442e-85ae-d3ddceaaa985',
    vehicleId: '20f3f453-774c-4e4e-9dd6-a3b3468e42f4',
    userId: '0d7a45e7-3483-4cc6-95b0-12e551002a7a',
    bidAmount: 300,
    fullName: 'Hanuman' },
  { id: 'acfff167-3b71-4f60-a229-95b5444e25e9',
    vehicleId: '20f3f453-774c-4e4e-9dd6-a3b3468e42f4',
    userId: '0d7a45e7-3483-4cc6-95b0-12e551002a7a',
    bidAmount: 200,
    fullName: 'Hanuman' } ];

 const total = reduceBids.reduce((bid, currentBid) => {  
        return bid + currentBid.bidAmount;
}, 0);   

console.log(total);
```

You should also specify seed (second reduce's parameter). Otherwise first array element will be taken as default seed so in your case you'll get `600` after first iteration but then that value gets passed as `bid` so you're trying to read something like `600.bidAmount` (`bid.bidAmount`) which makes no sense so you're getting `NaN` as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a NodeJS problem, this is a javascript problem. Check your reduce function. Refering to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) you can see that the first parameter of the reduction is the accumulator. You are using bid, which is being default defined as 0, and trying to access its 'bid amount' property, causing NaN.

Remove the suffix and use only `bid` in the sum and it should work.